# How to get extra parameter from AjaxRequest wicket 6

Tags: ajax, wicket, wicket-1.6

Hi all wicket pros out there,

I would like to get extra parameter I added to the AjaxRequest in the respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) method of a AbstractDefaultAjaxBehaviour.

I build the Wicket.Ajax.get(...) call by myself and I could manage that the respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) method of the AbstractDefaultAjaxBehaviour is invoked, but I get stock in how to get the extra parameters I added in my js call.

So here the code what I'm doing:

js that is called onSelect:

```
Wicket.ajax.get({'u':'callbackUrl','c':'componetId', 'ep':{'objectId':'OBJECT_ID'}});
```

java snippet of the AbstractDefaultAjaxBehaviour:

```
onSelectBehavior = new AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior(){
        @Override
        protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            //here I want to get the OBJECT_ID I added in the Wicket.Ajax.get call above
        }
};
```

The respond() method is invoked as expected, but I don't know how to get the OBJECT_ID.
Actually I'm not sure at all if I added the extra parameter in the right way to the wicket.ajax.get call.

In Wicket 1.4 I added the extra parameters as a url query string like `ajaxCallUrl...?objectId=OBJECT_ID` and in respond() I got them back from the RequestCycle `RequestCycle().get().getRequest().getParameter('objectId')`

If anyone could give me a hint, I would appreciate it :)
Thanks in advance,
Ronny

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is correct. You should be able to get the parameter like this:

```
@Override
protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target)
{
    getRequest().getRequestParameters().getParameterValue("objectId");
}
```

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187319/wicket-6-2-abstractdefaultajaxbehavior-getcallbackurl-no-longer-resolves-js-vari) for passing parameters directly from Wicket without constructing the ajax call yourself.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that worked, I was really close and you gave me the last hint I needed to get it :)